# LUP (PLU) decomposition failed with random matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, math, matrix

I try to code an LUP (or PLU it's the same) factorization in python. I have a code which works for small matrix (under a 4x4 size). However when I have tried it with a random generated matrix the decomposition has failed.

```
import numpy as np


def LUP_factorisation(A):
    """Find P, L and U : PA = LU"""
    U = A.copy()
    shape_a = U.shape
    n = shape_a[0]
    L = np.eye(n)
    P = np.eye(n)
    for i in range(n):
        print(U)
        k = i
        comp = abs(U[i, i])
        for j in range(i, n):
            if abs(U[j, i]) > comp:
                k = j
                comp = abs(U[j, i])
        line_u = U[k, :].copy()
        U[k, :] = U[i, :]
        U[i, :] = line_u
        print(U)
        line_p = P[k, :].copy()
        P[k, :] = P[i, :]
        P[i, :] = line_p
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            g = U[j, i] / U[i, i]
            L[j, i] = g
            U[j, :] -= g * U[i, :]
    return L, U, P


if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = np.array(
        [[1.0, 2.2, 58, 9.5, 42.65], [6.56, 58.789954, 4.45, 23.465, 6.165], [7.84516, 8.9864, 96.546, 4.654, 7.6514],
         [45.65, 47.985, 1.56, 3.9845, 8.6], [455.654, 102.615, 63.965, 5.6, 9.456]])
    L, U, P = LUP_factorisation(A)
    print(L @ U)
    print(P @ A)
```

With the example I gave it works: we have PA = LU. But when i do for example :

```py
A = np.random.rand(10, 10)
```

Then, i don't obtain a good result because PA is different of LU. Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@MattTimmermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5483526/matt-timmermans) writes you should swap rows in both L and U.

Normally this is implicitly handled by storing LU in A and then the swaps are automatically applied to both L and U. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#C_code_example

But you have split them so you have to add

```
    line_l = L[k, :].copy()
    L[k, :] = L[i, :]
    L[i, :] = line_l
```

Only testing it with diagonally dominant matrices is really bad; and only testing linear algebra routines with random matrices is known to be bad as their properties are very specific - and not "random". See work by Trefethen and his students, e.g. http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/14322

The goal of testing should be to find bugs - not to make test-cases so simple that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the diagonal of the input matrix A is dominant. So add some value to the diagonal of A, e.g.

```
A = A + np.eye(A.shape)
```

or

```
A = A + 100* np.eye(A.shape)
```

I hope that helps !

Comment: Great :-). And since you are rather new here: If you find some useful answers her in StackOverflow then you can give an upvote (orange up-arrow on the left of the text field). If you have asked a question and have got an answer, that solves your problem you might click "solved" (= check sign below the up/down arrows, which becomes green) too

Comment: here it is - Thanks :-)

Comment: @Yoann If the diagonal is dominant then you won't have to swap rows.  If your decomposition only works when the diagonal is dominant, it probably means that it has a bug related to swapping rows.  I notice you didn't adjust L at all when you swapped rows in P and U...

Answer (score 0):

i think by creating a matrix using random method you'll always have a mistake ( PA != LU) ,be cause the matrix generated does not  fulfill the requirements , the determinant of the matrix should be positive , not just the matrix but all the Mn (n=1-->P)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).